# Timer to restart function when completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm currently stuck on a problem with a timer.

I've got a function that is started by a timer every x seconds.
Now the function execution can sometimes take longer under different conditions.
So I want the timer to rerun only when it has completed the function.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Let's say you want to trigger a call to your method every 10 seconds. If the call takes 7 seconds, there will be a 3 second delay until the next call after it returns. If the call takes 12 seconds, do you want to wait 8 seconds for the next call, or do you want to sort of "sync up" the timer and immediately trigger, and then trigger on 22 seconds again? In other words, can you please explain the exact behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Hey Lasse, thanks for your reply. I want it to retrigger immediately after it finishes.

Comment: OK, so just need some more clarification. The call takes 12 seconds, immediately when it finishes you want to trigger the call again, let's say this call takes only 2 seconds (we're now up to 14 seconds after the whole thing started). Do you want to wait 6 seconds for the third call, or 8, in other words do you want to sort of re-start the 10 second cycles from 12 seconds going forward, or do you want to keep the original schedule, just handle the longer-than-normal calls as best you can?

Comment: I just want it to rerun as fast as it can. So I dont really care about how long the method takes to finish, but when it finished it has to start again immediately / as fast as possible. I was thinking if there was anyway of letting the timer know that the method has finished (some signal or state, maybe let the timer start a task and use the taskcompleted or something?)

Comment: Are you in any UI form or not?

Comment: Im using C# wpf with the MVVM pattern, trying to achieve this in my viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before it exits, your function could trigger an event. The event will be caught by another function, which will start the timer.

Comment: I guess this is the best way to go for me. Im now creating a class which contains the event like this:                                                                    class MyClass {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void Method() {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
Use it like this:

MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.MyEvent += new EventHandler(myObject_MyEvent);
myObject.Method();                             Then the method from the event will start a timer that runs only once and will get retriggered at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to avoid using a Timer class for this. The reason for this is precisely the problems you have with dealing this now.

The System.Threading.Timer class is re-entrant, which means that if the interval elapses before the previous trigger call returns, it will call the method again even while it is already executing. You need to handle cooperation between the method and the trigger in a way that makes the code a bit messy.

However, let's rethink the problem.

You want to

1. Call a method on an interval
2. If a method call takes longer to execute than the interval, immediately trigger again

A better way would be to dispense with the trigger and write your own using tasks.

Here's a very simple example:

```
public static async Task CallPeriodicAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> func,
    int intervalMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delay = Task.Delay(intervalMilliseconds, cancellationToken);
        await func(cancellationToken);
        await delay;
    }
}
```

You would start it like this:

```
CancellationToken cancellationToken = ...;
CallPeriodicAsync(async ct =>
{
    int timeToRun = 1000 + r.Next(14000);
    Console.WriteLine($"This time running for {timeToRun} ms");
    await Task.Delay(timeToRun, ct);
}, 10000, cancellationToken);
```

Sample output would be (I also had some Console.WriteLine in the CallPeriod method to say whether it will wait or immediately trigger in this run):

```
This time running for 12162 ms
trigger again immediately
This time running for 14706 ms
trigger again immediately
This time running for 12756 ms
trigger again immediately
This time running for 2187 ms
delay until next is 7813 ms
This time running for 5221 ms
delay until next is 4767 ms
This time running for 8866 ms
```

Basically this CallPeriod method will call your method and give it X milliseconds to complete. If it completes faster it will add a delay for the remainder, if it completes slower it will just restart the cycle.

This means that my question about "keeping the original interval" is still relevant.

For instance, keeping the original interval would result in this kind of triggering (`---*` is just the timeline), every 4 seconds:

```
v               v               v               v               v
*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*
[...]           [..................][.......]   [...]           [....
```

whereas my solution above would skew the cycle after a delay:

```
v               v               v                   v               v
*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*
[...]           [..................][.......]       [...]           [....
                                v                   ^
                                +-- because we got -+
                                 one second delayed
                                 here we're now one
                                 second late always
```

Comment: Very nice! Some suggestions: 1) add the `Async` suffix, 2) replace the `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)` with `while(true)`, to avoid having inconsistent canceling behavior (sometimes it throws, sometimes it's not) and 3) create the `Task.Delay` task before awaiting the `func` and `await` it afterwards, to get rid of the `Stopwatch` and the related time calculations.