# Continuous Async Ping inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, service, async-await, windows-services, ping

I need to monitor a list of hosts continuously. After N seconds, i need to check the list again. So, I tried to use the async ping inside a Windows Service.

I tried to follow tips from other posts related to the topic, but always my service stops shortly after starting it.

There are a problem with await in "OnElapsedTime" function.

Any one have an idea what is wrong? Bellow my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace PingAsyncService
{
    public partial class HyBrazil_Ping : ServiceBase

    {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        List<string> IPList = new List<string>();  //List of IPs


        public HyBrazil_Ping()
        {
            IPList.Add("192.168.0.1");
            IPList.Add("192.168.0.254");

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 5000; //number in miliseconds 
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        private async void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);

            var ResultList = await PingAsync();
            foreach(PingReply reply in ResultList)
            {
                WriteToFile(reply.Address.ToString() + ";" + reply.Status.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async Task<PingReply> PingAndProcessAsync(Ping pingSender, string ip)
        {
            var result = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000);
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            var tasks = IPList.Select(ip => PingAndProcessAsync(pingSender, ip));
            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            return results.ToList();
        }

        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most likely getting an exception in your async void method, which causes the exception to be thrown on a threadpool thread and then crashes it. Wrap in a try catch block and see

Comment: Ok, the exception message was: "An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.".

Then, the problem is in "await Task.WhenAll(tasks);" in PingAsync function. How i fix this? The async function returns correctly, but the call does not finished

Comment: You timer interval fires every 5 seconds, so it calls it again even tho the operations aren't finished yet. Set AutoReset = false for the timer and restart it manually

Comment: But the operations was finished! The problem was not a time. I see in txt file the sucess of first operation but i can't fire other call

Comment: Yes, the operation was finished the first time, how do you know that the 2nd/3rd etc times they are?

Comment: For while it's a simple test, i'm testing with local IPs and they are always available. Is there any deadlock in the code and i can't find it.

Comment: My guess is that you need to create a separate `Ping` object for each IP. A single `Ping` is probably unable to perform multiple concurrent operations.  Also you could take a look at a different technique for [periodic async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001972/timer-to-restart-function-when-completed/62002347#62002347), instead of using timers.

Comment: So, i must change this line? "var tasks = IPList.Select(ip => PingAndProcessAsync(pingSender, ip));". I can't think in another way, can you help me?

Comment: Don't use `Timer` here, use infinite loop with `Task.Delay()` instead. Break the loop in `OnStop()`, for example with `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 2):

In one of the comments you mentioned the error message as 
"An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method."

Chances are, the Ping object does not let simultaneous asynchronous calls.
Using a new Ping object everytime, on each call, might help as below.

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
    // Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tasks = IPList.Select(ip =>
    {
        using (var p= new Ping())
        {
            return PingAndProcessAsync(p, ip);
        }
    });
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToList();
}
```